# Iterate Object to update a specific property

Tags: javascript, object

Hi I'm struggling to find a way to loop throught my object to update the 'curr' property. I've googled, but not found an answer.

```
var myobj = {
    obj1: {
      curr: 0,
      count: "count1"
    },

    obj2: {
      curr: 0,
      count: "count2"
    },

    obj3: {
      curr: 0,
      count: "count3"
    }
}
```

I tried to use the following..

```
for (var property in myobj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        // do stuff
        console.log(property) //which gives me obj1, obj2, obj3  BUT i need to access and set values in obj1.curr, obj2.curr and obj3.curr
}
```

Really struggling to figure out how to achieve this....

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there:

```
for (var property in myobj) {
    if (myobj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      myobj[property].curr = 1;  // etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` only loops through the property names. You need to explicitly get the object using that property.
Also make sure you test hasOwnProperty for the proper object..

```
for (var property in myobj) {
    if (myobj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        myobj[property].curr = 1;
}
```